# Can we skip the custom metadata object name field during setup?

Tags: managed-package, metadata, package, custom-metadata, data-model

I've a sync status that I need to map across platforms for which I'm planning to use the custom metadata type because of the following reasons.

1. I've a list of key-value pair records that needs to be set up initially during packaging.
2. I might add/delete/update the key-value pair through during releases.

Now, my understanding is that Custom Metedata is the better approach than Custom Setting because of the easy support for upgrades and gets directly added to the package.

But, when I try to create the metadata type, there are two additional fields that get added.

- Label
- Custom Metadata object name

I understand custom metadata falls under a sObject model and has the object name by default. Is there a provision to skip these additional fields so that I can have just the key-value pair in the records? I'm just curious since the data would look much cleaner.

Thanks in Advance! Peace!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Label and Custom Metadata Object Name are Salesforce provided standard fields for Custom metadata types and those cannot be removed.

You should create a new View reaching "Manage Records" and click on "Create new view" and place your desired key value fields in that. That will be easier to view.

Comment: Depending on your key requirements, you can consider using one of these standard fields *as* your key field.